# How to calculate MLE of variance?

Tags: variance, maximum-likelihood

How to calculate MLE of variance for different distributions?

E.g. binomial?

Comment: The variance is an attribute of a random variable, what random variable are you interested in finding the variance for?

Maximum Likelihood Estimates, are estimates of parameters.  In the case of a binomial distribution, you have a single parameter $\theta$.  The estimator for $\theta$, $\hat{\theta}$ has a variance.

Answer (score 1):

For some given distribution, the variance will be a function of parameters.

ML estimation has a [functional invariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood#Functional_invariance) property (well, it actually has two such properties, but we're only concerned with one of them here) which means that the MLE of a function of parameters is that function of the MLE's of the parameters: $\widehat{g(\theta)} = g(\hat{\theta})$.

Which means that you compute the MLE of the parameters that the variance is a function of, and then substitute those estimates into the formula for the variance of the distribution.

In the case of the binomial, $\text{Var}(X) = np(1-p)$, of which $n$ is given and $p$ is a parameter; applying the principle just stated is trivial ... and a common textbook exercise, so I'll leave it for you to do the last tiny step.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36893/discussion-on-answer-by-glen-b-how-to-calculate-mle-of-variance).